# Can not read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can not read property of push of undefined. Why is it undefined? When I do `console.log(columnsArray[i])` it shows me the value. I don't understand.

```
var columnsArray = ["col1","col2","col3"];
var indexArray = [];
function submitIndex() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= columnsArray.length ; i++) {
    if ($("#" + columnsArray[i]).is(":checked") === true) {
      indexArray.push(columnsArray[i]); 
    } else {
      console.log(columnsArray[i] + "is not checked");
    }
  } 
  var indexArray = indexArray.filter(onlyUnique);
  console.log(indexArray);
}
```

Comment: The error is saying that `indexArray` is undefined, not `columnsArray[i]`. Where exactly have you defined it?

Comment: You are trying to access `indexArray` before defining it.

Comment: indexArray is declared !

Comment: Not when you call `push()` it isnt

Comment: @PopAlexandru Where is it declared? (Before .push)

Comment: i forgot to write but indexArray is a global varieble devlared in top of my script . indexArray = [];

Comment: now it should work can please send your complete code

Comment: remove `var` from `var indexArray = indexArray.`

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: @Satpal that was it , thank you and God bless you :)

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

In the line:

```
var indexArray = indexArray.filter(onlyUnique);
```

You are trying to redeclare the `indexArray` variable after it was already declared before the loop.

It will cause the variable to be hoisted so the first declaration before the loop will be ignored so `indexArray` will be `undefined` inside the loop .
Please take a look at [**Hoisting**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) and [**var** keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)  MDN References for further details about it.

**Solution:**

To fix that you need to remove `var` keyword in this line:

```
indexArray = indexArray.filter(onlyUnique);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my fiddle here for [error](https://jsfiddle.net/v6khbrvk/) replicated and then see the [solution here](https://jsfiddle.net/v6khbrvk/1/)

Things to note are these

```
var columnsArray = ["col1","col2","col3"];
var indexArray = [];
function submitIndex(indexArray) {
  for (var i = 0; i < columnsArray.length ; i++) //you dont need to go till 
  columnsArray length as this is 0 based indexed array not 1 so removed = 
  from here
  {
 console.log('i='+i+' and columnsArray[i]='+columnsArray[i]);
  if ($("#" + columnsArray[i]).is(":checked") === true) {
     indexArray.push(columnsArray[i]); 
   } else {
     console.log(columnsArray[i] + "is not checked");
   }
  } 
 // var indexArray = indexArray.filter(onlyUnique); I dont have onlyUnique 
 filter so commented out
 console.log(indexArray);
 }
 submitIndex(indexArray);
```

1. You need to iterate array upto length-1 so you can remove equality comparison for .length of an array
2. Pass the parameter to function and use that it would be more cleaner and you can do this with other checkboxes as well
3. Not sure about your onlyUnique filter so commented out but you should be able to use it and
4. Dont use var to declare variable again to declare the array again instead place the filtered result in another array and return that array.